# uglifyjs-webpack-plugin security vulnerability

Tags: npm, webpack

I'm getting a security vulnerability on uglifyjs-webpack-plugin package

```
  Moderate        Cross-Site Scripting

  Package         serialize-javascript

  Patched in      >=2.1.1

  Dependency of   uglifyjs-webpack-plugin [dev]

  Path            uglifyjs-webpack-plugin > serialize-javascript

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1426
```

All the fixes I've come accrss suggest upgrading `serialize-javascript` to latest, but since I'm not using it  directly, I'm not sure what to do here. Any ideas?

I'm using this version `"uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the [package.json](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/blob/master/package.json). The plugin has a dependency of `"serialize-javascript": "^1.7.0"` and [caret range](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004) means that `<2.0.0` will be downloaded, actually the last acceptable available version is `1.9.1`, where the fix isn't presented.

Because the repository now is archived (considered deprecated), you could patch it by yourself or if it's possible to switch to the  [terser-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin) how documentation suggests.

Comment: I've decided to switch to terser. Thanks